# Recessed 6 inch can lighting retrofit sag

Tags: retrofit

I currently am trying to install some retrofit led Halo lights into some existing airtight cans in my kitchen. I was able to successfully install most of them but some of the recessed light cans are either sagging or the halo retrofit doesn’t fit completely over. Is there an easy fix to get these tight to the ceiling?

[image: retrofit]

Comment: It looks like the can is sagging, not the light. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

When I've had that problem it was usually something in the ceiling obstructing things. Either the junction box or tension on one of the cables, extra insulation etc. They are tricky to remove but I would pull the problem ones and try and adjust what's up there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like both the light and the can are sagging.  That's pretty common when changing out recessed lights because of the forces you inadvertently apply to the can while trying to pull out the old trim and socket.

To fix the can sagging, pull the LED assembly down and loosen the three mounting screws around the rim of the can.  The mounting holes are eccentric so you have some play.  Push the can up so it is flush or slightly higher than flush with the drywall and retighten the mounting screws.

Before you push the LED assembly back up, bend the legs of the springs outward so they press harder against the clips on the inside of the can.  Then when you press the LED back up, it will "stick" better.

Answer (score 0):

Those usually have hook springs inside that are not easy to install

Make sure you used the right hole to hook the springs

Comment: Your first sentence - are you implying that the end user has to install the springs on the fixture himself, or that the springs are installed, but there is difficulty getting the fixture installed into the ceiling? I've never installed one of these, so I'm not sure which it is. I've watched (TV shows) these be installed and they always _seem_ easy, but it's always easy on TV...